# while loop does not exit when the condition is not met

Tags: bash, while-loop

When running the code below, I’d like to read a user-input answer until it is one of the 6 possible answers (`[abcABC]`), else continue with the next loop.

However, it does not exit the while loop when I enter one of the accepted answers.

I tried `[]` and `[[]]` for the conditions, I tried to place all of the conditions into one pair of square brackets, I tried to use `|` and `||`, none of them worked as expected.

```sh
while [ "$ans" != "a" ] || [ "$ans" != "A" ] || [ "$ans" != "b" ] || \
      [ "$ans" != "B" ] || [ "$ans" != "c" ] || [ "$ans" != "C" ]; do
    read ans

    case $ans in
      [aA]) echo "aA"         ;;
      [bB]) echo "bB"         ;;
      [cC]) echo "cC"         ;;
      *)    echo "Try again." ;;
    esac
done
```

It should read in loop until one of the accepted answer is given; then it should continue with the following code (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop condition is always true, and Bash correctly loops forever.

Consider a simplified version:

```
[ "$ans" != "a" ] || [ "$ans" != "b" ]
```

- If `ans` is `a` then it becomes `false || true` which is true.
- If `ans` is `b` then it becomes `true || false` which is true.
- If `ans` is `x` then it becomes `true || true` which is true.

You wanted `&&` instead of `||`. Alternatively, do it in a single comparison: `[[ "$ans" != [aAbBcC] ]]`

Comment: This is the perfect answer! Yes, I see the reason. I have no idea why missed this. Anyway, thank you for the simplifacation --- I did not know I can use regex syntax instead of a string in comparison.